# how to use multiple copies of any Subview(created in xib) from xib file

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, uiview

I am using xib to create view for my project. The condition is:

I have multiple `UIView` IBoutlet's Object.

```
IBOutlet UIView *viewOpenDoor;
IBOutlet UIView *viewOpenDoor_Second;
```

`viewOpenDoor` is only connected to one of the view in xib. 
Now i am using this code to reuse the same view multiple times in `viewdidload` method-

```
[viewOpenDoor setFrame:CGRectMake(30, 80, viewOpenDoor.frame.size.width, viewOpenDoor.frame.size.height)];
[self.view addSubview:viewOpenDoor];
viewOpenDoor.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
viewOpenDoor.layer.borderWidth = 0.9f;
viewOpenDoor.layer.cornerRadius = 6.0f;

 [viewOpenDoor setHidden:YES];

viewOpenDoor_Second = [[UIView alloc] init];
viewOpenDoor_Second = [viewOpenDoor copy];

[viewOpenDoor_Second setFrame:CGRectMake(184, 80, viewOpenDoor.frame.size.width, viewOpenDoor.frame.size.height)];

[self.view addSubview:viewOpenDoor_Second];
```

it's giving exception-

```
-[UIView copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x95ba140



Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x95ba140'
```

So, my question is how can i reuse this one `IBOutlet` object created in xib, multiple times with different instances?

Comment: Thanks in advance, i am awaiting for someone's quick response.

Comment: i can create multiple copies in xib file of that particular view and use them but i want to know the way to reuse the one object multiple times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You load the `xib` into a `UINib` and instantiate all the copies you want from that `UINib`.

Then access the outlet of the copy of the whole `xib`. You cant copy a view, you can only instatiate multiple "copies" from the same `UINib`.

You can store the `UINib` in an instance variable if you plan to create more later.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:- Reference all the instances(that you want to connect) of `UIView` to XIB file as shown in below image.
[image]

Comment: it treats that view as multiple instance pointing single object.